# Best resource to learn Metal API and graphics

Tags: graphics, 3d, metal

I am an API level amateur, I have an idea of the GFX pipeline but nothing to thorough

I don't want to start with **OpenGL** and want to learn via **Metal** with Objective-C and not swift

Are you aware of any book/video tutorials or something that teaches you Metal ? 
More interested to learn the 3D side than compute

Also I am looking for something that I can run from command line, I have seen Apple provided Metal projects that run on xcode

Any help, guidance, etc is appreciated.

Comment: You have to use Xcode to develop Metal apps. An Objective-C impl of prefix sum implemented as multiple Metal shader render steps can be found here. https://github.com/mdejong/MetalPrefixSum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This website is awesome:
https://metalbyexample.com/

You can run Metal in playground with Swift:
http://metalkit.org/2016/07/31/metal-performance-shaders-for-the-ipad-playground.html